# How do I make a virtual node using MPF?

Tags: c#, vsx

I am creating a new project type using MPF.

I want to create a type of node where the backing for that node doesn't actually exist anywhere.  To keep it simple, I just want to generate the captions on the fly.

I have created a new node subclass from HierarchyNode because it will eventually have children.  I have subclassed the FolderNode so I can determine which folders will have these virtual nodes as children.  I am using Get/SetMetadata to do that and it works fine.  I overrode GetProperty in MyFolderNode so that if the folder type is a "normal" folder, it just routes to base.  Otherwise it returns a VirtualNode for FirstChild.  The VirtualNodes create their next sibling and set NextSibling to it.  TL;DR: Code follows.

My problem is that it isn't working. Specifically, when I click on the "Expand this folder" icon, it turns blue (so the click is registering) but it stays blue and the node isn't expanded.  Debugging shows that trying to expand the folder does hit GetProperty requesting FirstChild and it does return the id of the first child. After that the VirtualNode is queried twice to see if it is expandable.  Then it is queried for the caption.  Then the icon.  Then nothing.

Here is the code for my FolderNode subclass:

```
public class AndroidFolderNode : FolderNode
{
    public enum FolderType
    {
        Normal,
        JavaSource
    }

    public string[] VirtualNodes = new[]
                                    {
                                        "Virtual Node One",
                                        "Virtual Node Two",
                                        "Virtual Node Three"
                                    };

    private FolderType mFolderType;
    public FolderType Type
    {
        get
        {
            return mFolderType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (mFolderType != value)
            {
                mFolderType = value;
                OnInvalidateItems(this);
            }
        }
    }

    private HierarchyNode mVirtualChild;

    public AndroidFolderNode(ProjectNode root, string relativePath, ProjectElement element)
        : base(root, relativePath, element)
    {
        var t = element.GetMetadata("Type");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t))
        {
            Type = FolderType.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            FolderType tempType;
            if (Enum.TryParse(t, true, out tempType))
            {
                Type = tempType;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override NodeProperties CreatePropertiesObject()
    {
        return new AndroidFolderNodeProperties(this);
    }


    public override object GetProperty(int propId)
    {
        object result = null;
        switch ((__VSHPROPID) propId)
        {
            case __VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_FirstChild:
                goto case __VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_FirstVisibleChild;

            case __VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_FirstVisibleChild:
                if (Type == FolderType.Normal)
                {
                    result = (int)((this.FirstChild != null) ? this.FirstChild.ID : VSConstants.VSITEMID_NIL);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mVirtualChild == null)
                    {
                        mVirtualChild = new VirtualFolderNode(this, 0);
                    }
                    result = mVirtualChild.ID;
                }
                break;
            default:
                result = base.GetProperty(propId);
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my VirtualNode:

```
class VirtualFolderNode : HierarchyNode
{
    private static Guid _guid = new Guid("DD264E51-2E66-4BCC-A8A6-DE3BDE890DED");

    private int mIdx;
    private AndroidFolderNode mParent;
    private VirtualFolderNode mSibling;

    public VirtualFolderNode(AndroidFolderNode parent, int idx)
        : base(parent.ProjectMgr)
    {
        mParent = parent;
        mIdx = idx;
        Parent = parent;

        if (idx < parent.VirtualNodes.Length)
        {
            mSibling = new VirtualFolderNode(parent, idx + 1);
            NextSibling = mSibling;
        }
    }

    public override string Url
    {
        get { return Parent.Url + "\\VNode" + mIdx; }
    }

    public override string Caption
    {
        get { return mParent.VirtualNodes[mIdx]; }
    }

    public override Guid ItemTypeGuid
    {
        get { return _guid; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! (Side note: I've never had to answer my own question before.)

The problem, it appears, is that the HierarchyNode.GetIconHandle(bool open) simply returns null.  Overriding GetIconHandle in VirtualNode allows it to be displayed as expected.  So I added this to VirtualNode and bada bing, bada boom:

```
    public override object GetIconHandle(bool open)
    {
        return ProjectMgr.ImageHandler.GetIconHandle(open ? (int)ProjectNode.ImageName.OpenFolder : (int)ProjectNode.ImageName.Folder);
    }
```